# How to delete an object on c#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible if we delete an object from the class itself? I have a class like below:

Parent Class:

```
public class ModelBase<T>
{
    .....

    public void Delete()
    {
        this = null // <-- it's not works
    }

    .....
}
```

Children Class:

```
public class Company : ModelBase<Company>
{
    public string Name;

    public Company(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Declaring on UI Layer:

```
var company = new Company("Company X");
Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
company.Delete();
Console.WriteLine(company.Name); // <-- this should be empty or null
```

Deleting the object should be on parent class. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why not company=null;

Comment: ups sorry, i mean on my questions it should be deleting object from parrent class. I update my question.

Comment: @AdiWinata: You are confusing `class` and (`instance` or `object`).  You can't, easily, change a class structure at runtime.  And your `company` object, which is an instance of the `Company` class, is a top-level object.. Objects can not delete themselves.  As Leo mentions in the answers, you set an object to `null` and let the GC handle the rest.

Comment: Perhaps you can put the `Name` in the base class. Then in base class set it null.

Comment: Setting a variable to null will not remove an object. The object gets automatically cleaned up when no more variables refer to it, but `this = null` is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

No, in C# the garbage collection does the "deleting" for you eventually.

If there`s something inside the class you want to manually dispose like a connection you can use the Disposable Pattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern).

The closest you can come to manually deleting the object is forcing the garbage collector to collect with GC.Collect (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: how to disposing the object? In my case, first declare an Company Object and processing it with some process after, and after i used company, i need to deletes it and ensuring it hasn't stor anymore in memory. Can you give some example?

Comment: In c# you cannot ensure the object was deleted, the only guarantee that c# garbage collector gives you is that the object will eventually be deleted. If you call the "GC.Collect" the garbage collector will search for all unreferenced objects and delete them, i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously setting `this` to `null` inside `Delete` function has not effect outside of the function (if it ever compile).

Destroying an object from itself is also very dangerous as you would have to be sure that no code afterward would access that object (or the caller stack). IN fact, in C#, the idea does not make more sense as it is **garbage collected** which imply that if you are inside a member function, then you have at least one reference to the object in which case it would never be garbage collected at that point anyway.

Also assuming that the object company was destroyed (and `company` set to null), you would get a null pointer exception when calling `.Name`.

Assuming that company object is not disposable (does not implement `IDisposable`), then your code should look like:

```
var company = new Company("Company X");
Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
company = null;
Console.WriteLine(company?.Name); // <-- this should be empty or null
```

Well, we assume that real code is somewhat more complex than that as otherwise you could simply replace last line by:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

However if you company object implement `IDisposable`, then usually you should use the `using` keyword if which case setting the object to null would not make sense.

```
using (var company = new Company("Company X"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
}

Console.WriteLine();
```

**Your `Delete` function is really a bad idea** and clearly show a lack of understanding of C#.

If you want to know if an object has been destroyed, you could use `WeekReference`. As an example, it can be used for a cache. See reference documentation for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx.

Your whole code make little sense. If you have only one variable, then it is trivial for a decent programmer to know when the object is alive. If you have multiple objects, then you should use a collection (for ex. `List<Company>`) in which case, you would obviously remove a company from the collection if you don't want it anymore and then when you use that collection, you would not see it anyway.

Alternatively for complexe cases, you might use a dictionary, a set or a flag to remember if you should process a given object. This might be useful for example when iterating a collection as usually you should not modifying while you are enumerating its items.

Comment: in my case, first i declare an object Company, then processing it to some process and then deletes it and then ensuring it doesn't exist anymore in memory. How to do that in c#? `company.Delete();
            Assert.That(customer.Id, Is.Null.Or.Empty);` <--how to make this test method works? Is it possible?

Comment: Forget your idea of `company.Delete();`. It cannot works that way. We already gave you a lot of information and explain why it is not possible to it that way. Thus, you have to decide what you want to do instead. Other peoples snd myself already gave many suggestions. From your question we cannot determine what is best for you as the sample is too simple to know the reel problem (if there is one).